# PHP conditionally retrieve data from array

Tags: php, arrays, performance, filter, slice

I'm pretty new to PHP. I need to filter a response from server, to improve performance. I have a payload splitted by the pipe char, and sliced to only retrieve the data I need:

```
$alllogsplitted = explode("|",$row['PAYLOAD']); 
print_r(array_slice($alllogsplitted, 23, 22));
```

The data in every position have the same structure, in ex: `A1;0;0` means: `type;firstvalue;secondvalue`. Now I want to get only the data if the `firstvalue` is different from zero. The actual response is:

```
  Array
  (
      [0] => A1;0;0
      [1] => A2;0;0
      [2] => A3;0;0 
      [3] => A4;0;0
      [4] => A5;0;1593720
      [5] => A6;0;0
      [6] => A7;0;29
      [7] => A8;3;0 // this data is to retrieve
      [8] => A9;0;0
      [9] => A13;0;0
      [10] => A14;0;0
      [11] => A23;1;33802 // this data is to retrieve
      [12] => A25;0;2706254
      [13] => A27;0;100
      [14] => A30;0;0
      [15] => A31;0;100785
      [16] => A32;0;0
      [17] => A33;0;0
      [18] => A34;0;0
      [19] => A47;0;128694
      [20] => A48;0;2
      [21] => B1;0;145
  )
  Array
  (
      [0] => A1;0;0
      [1] => A2;0;0
      [2] => A3;0;0
      [3] => A4;0;0
      [4] => A5;0;1593688
      [5] => A6;0;0
      [6] => A7;0;29
      [7] => A8;3;0 // this data is to retrieve
      [8] => A9;0;0
      [9] => A13;0;0
      [10] => A14;0;0
      [11] => A23;0;33802
      [12] => A25;0;2706254
      [13] => A27;0;100
      [14] => A30;0;0
      [15] => A31;0;100785
      [16] => A32;0;0
      [17] => A33;0;0
      [18] => A34;0;0
      [19] => A47;0;128694
      [20] => A48;0;2
      [21] => B1;0;145
  )
  Array
  (
      [0] => A1;0;0
      [1] => A2;0;0
      [2] => A3;2;1 // this data is to retrieve
      [3] => A4;0;0
      [4] => A5;0;1593688
      [5] => A6;0;0
      [6] => A7;0;26
      [7] => A8;0;981
      [8] => A9;0;0
      [9] => A13;0;0
      [10] => A14;0;0
      [11] => A23;0;33802
      [12] => A25;0;2706254
      [13] => A26;0;3
      [14] => A27;0;100
      [15] => A30;0;0
      [16] => A31;0;100785
      [17] => A32;0;0
      [18] => A33;0;1
      [19] => A34;0;0
      [20] => A47;0;128694
      [21] => A48;0;2
  )
```

And I want instead this response:

```
  Array
  (
      [7] => A8;3;0 // this data is to retrieve
      [11] => A23;1;33802 // this data is to retrieve
  )
  Array
  (
      [7] => A8;3;0 // this data is to retrieve
  )
  Array
  (
      [2] => A3;2;1 // this data is to retrieve
  )
```

How can I get this? Thanks for help!

Comment: Do you have any attempts to show us you made to try and solve this yourself?

Comment: array_filter() takes a callback.

Comment: I try some for loop, but I do not now PHP array method, and I do not have positive results, so I ask You for help to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function should do the trick for you. It runs through the array and only keeps the instances based on the conditions you specified

```
function filterArrayForResult($array) {
    $newArray = array_filter($array, function($string) {
        $stringArray = explode(';', $string); // Creates an array from the string

        return ($stringArray[1] != 0); // Only keep the elements that equals true
    });

    return $newArray // Return the result
}
```

Comment: thank you, it works very well!

Answer (score 1):

This might help: $array is the array you want to filter

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $columns = explode(';', $value);
    if($columns[1] != 0) {
        $columns = implode(';', $columns);
        $result[$key] = $columns;
    }
}
```